Play simultaneously to multiple soundcards with NAudio
I am working on an audio player application on .NET and am using NAudio as the base class. I need this app to be able to play one file simultaneously to more than one soundcard. I've read about it online and the consensus is saying the best way is to simply open the file several times, but this cannot work for me as the file size / soundcards / audio pipelines in general can end up being heavy and I would like to keep good performance.
I then have tried to create a MultiOutput class in NAudio that reads the buffer, stores it in memory and is able to provide the backup insted of triggering a source.Read() all the time. This class seems to work good on my machine, but I would like pro developers feedbacks to make this more reliable in a pro application, as I am not very familiar with CSharp and NAudio yet and I might forget something very important for later.
Limitations for this alpha version:

All following pipelines must connect to this SampleProvider using a MultiOutputConnector (see below)
All pipelines must be on same sample rate and so on (using sample rate converters to / from 32 bit float)
The offset and count parameters are not yet taken into account
Does not handle end end of files, which does not matter to me as I plan to use this after a MixingSampleProvider with ReadFully turned on (so the sample provider is endless)

Here is the MultiOutput Class :
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using NAudio.Utils;


namespace NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A unit backing up the buffer it gets to distribute it to other destinations at the same time
    /// </summary>
    public class MultiOutput : ISampleProvider
    {
        private readonly ISampleProvider source;
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new MultiOutput unit, based on the given source. Must be followed
        /// only by MultiOutputConnectors in all pipelines.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">Source of samples</param>
        public MultiOutput(ISampleProvider source)
        {
            this.source = source;
            if (WaveFormat == null)
            {
                WaveFormat = source.WaveFormat;
            }
        }


       

        /// <summary>
        /// The output WaveFormat of this sample provider
        /// </summary>
        public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get; private set; }
      
        float[] bufferbackup;
    

        int offsetbackup;
        int countbackup;
        int outputbackup;



        /// <summary>
        /// Reads samples from this sample provider
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="buffer">Sample buffer</param>
        /// <param name="offset">Offset into sample buffer</param>
        /// <param name="count">Number of samples required</param>
        /// <returns>Number of samples read</returns>
        public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
      
            offsetbackup = offset;
            countbackup = count;


            lock (source)
            {
                float[] newsamples = new float[count];

                outputbackup = source.Read(newsamples, offset, count);
                BuffPaste(newsamples, ref buffer);
                bufferbackup = newsamples; //BuffCopy(newsamples);           
                return outputbackup;

            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Simulates a Read but fills the buffer using the backuped one instead
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="buffer">Sample buffer</param>
        /// <param name="offset">Offset into sample buffer</param>
        /// <param name="count">Number of samples required</param>
        /// <returns>Number of samples read</returns>
        public int FakeRead(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            lock (bufferbackup)
            {
                BuffPaste(bufferbackup, ref buffer);
                return outputbackup;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Select which of Read or FakeRead should be used to fill the buffer depending
        /// on caller
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="buffer">Sample buffer</param>
        /// <param name="offset">Offset into sample buffer</param>
        /// <param name="count">Number of samples required</param>
        /// <param name="Connection">Object calling</param>
        /// <returns>Number of samples read</returns>
        public int AppropriateRead(float[] buffer, int offset, int count, MultiOutputConnector Connection)
        {
            ReadRequestsSinceMaster += 1;
            if(ReadRequestsSinceMaster == AmountOfOutputs | (bufferbackup == null || bufferbackup.Length == 0) | MasterConnection == null)
            {
                MasterConnection = Connection;                
            }

            if (Connection == MasterConnection)
            {
                ReadRequestsSinceMaster = 0;
                return Read(buffer, offset, count);                
            }
            else
            {
                return FakeRead(buffer, offset, count);
            }
        }

        int ReadRequestsSinceMaster = 0;
        int AmountOfOutputs = 0;
        MultiOutputConnector MasterConnection = null;
        /// <summary>
        /// Register a new MultiOutputConnector to this MultiOutput 
        /// </summary>
        public void Register(MultiOutputConnector Input)
        {
            AmountOfOutputs += 1;
            if (MasterConnection == null)
            {
                MasterConnection = Input;
            }
        }

        public void UnRegister(MultiOutputConnector Input)
        {
            AmountOfOutputs = Math.Max(0, AmountOfOutputs - 1) ;
            if (MasterConnection == Input)
            {               
                MasterConnection = null;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a copy of the given buffer in a new object
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="buffer">The buffer to copy</param>
        /// <returns>the copied buffer</returns>
        public float[] BuffCopy(float[] buffer)
        {
            float[] secondbuffer = new float[buffer.Length];
            for (var i = 0; i <= buffer.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                float val = buffer[i];
                secondbuffer[i] = val;
            }              
            return secondbuffer;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Overwrites a buffer with another buffers content
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="buffer">The buffer to copy</param>
        /// <param name="destinationbuffer">The buffer to overwrite</param>
        public void BuffPaste(float[] buffer, ref float[] destinationbuffer)
        {            
            for (var i = 0; i <= buffer.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                destinationbuffer[i] = buffer[i];           
            }           
        }

    }
}


You must connect to this class using MultiOutputConnector, using as many as you like. Those two work together and are supposed totally transparent for all other NAudio components.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using NAudio.Utils;

namespace NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A connector for the MultiOutput unit allowing to connect a second pipeline to a single input
    /// </summary>
    public class MultiOutputConnector : ISampleProvider, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly MultiOutput source;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new MultiOutputConnector and registers it to the given MultiOutput
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">MultiOutput Base Class</param>
        public MultiOutputConnector(MultiOutput source)
        {
            this.source = source;
            source.Register(this);
            if (WaveFormat == null)
            {
                WaveFormat = source.WaveFormat;
            }

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            source.UnRegister(this);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

  


        /// <summary>
        /// The output WaveFormat of this sample provider
        /// </summary>
        public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get; private set; }
    


        /// <summary>
        /// Reads samples from this sample provider
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="buffer">Sample buffer</param>
        /// <param name="offset">Offset into sample buffer</param>
        /// <param name="count">Number of samples required</param>
        /// <returns>Number of samples read</returns>
        public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
              lock (source)
            {
                return source.AppropriateRead(buffer, offset, count, this);
            }
        }


    }
}


How to use
Simply insert them as two steps in your pipeline (This example below is extracted from my tests project which is in VB).
Note that new outputs can be assigned to the MultiOutput or removed from it at any time without affecting playback on other devices
  Dim afr = New AudioFileReader("C:\Users\Public\Music\Ehrling - Lounge.mp3")
  Dim mixer = New MixingSampleProvider({afr1}) With {.ReadFully = True}

  'Create Multiout Device in pipeline
  Dim multiout = New MultiOutput(mixer)


  'Output 1
  Dim multioutconnector = New MultiOutputConnector(multiout)
  Dim DSO1 = New DirectSoundOut()
  DSO1.Init(multioutconnector)
  DSO1.Play()

  'Output 2
  Dim multioutconnector2 = New MultiOutputConnector(multiout)
  Dim DSO2 = New DirectSoundOut(DirectSoundOut.Devices(0).Guid)
  DSO2.Init(multioutconnector)
  DSO2.Play()


This solution is working good as long as all soundcards and pipelines in general are working at the same speed, bit rate / depth and channels. Because the MultiOutput keeps the backup of the buffer, it ensures all soundcards get the same buffer at (almost) the same time and they keep in sync (although each hardware introduces a different latency, but that could be corrected using a delay on the shortest ones).
I am asking for feedback because I'm surprised nobody tried this before (at least not to my knowledge). I also have a variation of this idea allowing me to separate different channels of a pipeline to different destinations by having the Connector class picking one of the channels only, its WaveFromat being modified accordingly. Speaking of that, huge thank you to Mark and all NAudio contributors for your insane work!
Thank you all for feedback!
